# Nested flexbox inconsistency in Safari

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

Please check the following code snippet. The `height: 100%;` declaration is honored in every mayor browser but Safari. For Safari, `flex-basis: 50px;` apparently "voids" the height setting.

I feel this is a bug in Safari. However, since the layout is not straightforward, I don't know enough about the specs in order to be sure. Does anyone know if the behavior of the other browsers is the "right" behavior or if this is just a grey area? And, if it's a bug, where should I report it?

Browsers tried:

- Chrome 116
- Edge 117
- Firefox 118
- Safari 16.6

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  
  width: 500px;
  background: black;
}

.middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  
  flex-basis: 50px; /* this declaration makes a difference ONLY in Safari */

  width: 400px;
  background: red;
}

.inner {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 700px;

  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="inner"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is how this looks in Safari:
[image]

And this is how it looks in the other browsers:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want outer and middle to be the same height, why has outer 300px and middle 100%?

Have you tried giving them the same height?

Since inner is a child of middle and has `min-height: 700px;` it will make middle and outer also bigger. Then you put `height: 100%` on middle, which will be the 700px. Outer stays as is because of the absolute value `height: 300px`

Comment: There's no real reason to do it this way. I'm just curious as to why it behaves differently in Safari, and as to whether it's a bug or an undefined part of the specs.

Comment: Safari obviously handles things different than Chrome / Edge or Firefox, since it has a different Engine. My solution would work and prevent this from happening in Safari though. Alternatively you could just remove the `flex-basis`from middle

Comment: There is no bug listed on https://caniuse.com/?search=flex-basis so I would say it's Safaris specs.